# How to Invoke a Method When All of the Parallel HTTP Requests Are Completed?

Tags: android, asynchronous, retrofit2, rx-java2, rx-android

I need to get the categories, and then get the channels of that categories, and finally invoke a method when all categories and their channels are retrieved from the server. I guess that I need to use RxJava, but I could not find a similar implementation. (Preferably without using lambda/retrolambda expressions).

```java
@GET("/api/{categoryId})
Call<Category> getCategory(@Path("categoryId") String categoryId)


private void getCategories() {
    for (Tab t : tabs) {
        Call<Category> getCategory = videoAPI.getCategory(t.getId());
        getCategory.enqueue(new Callback<Category>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Category> call, Response<Category> response) {
                Category cat = response.body();
                categories.add(cat);
                // I will call the getChannels(String categoryId) method here, 
                // however I think implementing RxJava would be much better.
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Category> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i(TAG, "failure: " + t.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with

```
Observable
    .fromArray(/*your list of observables go here, make sure that within flatMap you get as type Observable<T>, not Observable<List<T>>*/)
    .flatMap(/*here you subscribe every item to a different thread, so they're parallel requests: subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())*/)
    .subscribe (/*each request*/,/*error*/,/*completed all requests*/)
```

Now your request needs to be of type Observable

```
@GET("/api/{categoryId}) 
Observable<Category> getCategory(@Path("categoryId") String categoryId)
```

Example code in **Java**:

```
// Setup a list of observables
List<Observable<Category>> parallelRequests = new ArrayList<>();
for (Tab t : tabs) {
    parallelRequests.add(videoAPI.getCategory(t.getId()));
}
Observable[] array = new Observable[parallelRequests.size()];

// Convert the list to array
parallelRequests.toArray(array);

Observable
        .fromArray(array)
        .flatMap(observable -> observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()))
        .subscribe(o -> {
            // each request is fulfilled
        }, Throwable::printStackTrace, () -> finishFunctionHere());
```

Or if you're using **Kotlin**

```
Observable
// The asterisk is called "spread operator": It converts an array to vararg
.fromArray(*tabs.map { api.getCategory(it.getId()) }.toTypedArray())
.flatMap { it.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()) }
.subscribe({ category ->
    // onEach
}, Throwable::printStackTrace, {
    // All requests were fulfilled
})
```

Comment: Thank you, but I would really appreciate if you could make the code complete. I cannot seem to construct the array of observables from the category id's of categories in tab object. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you, however I am getting this error: invalid method reference
non-static method printStackTrace() cannot be referenced from a static context. I will mark your answer accepted, though.

Comment: Your function needs to be static, otherwise use a lambda end call throwable.printStackTrace() (hope that works)